# Do protocol buffers support byte[] fields?

Tags: android, arrays, protocol-buffers

I am trying to update the Android BluetoothChat example's code to use Protobuf for more structured data exchange. I also need byte[] array fields to send arbitrary data like an image byte array but on trying to compile the .proto file, I get the below error.

*protofiles/bluetoothmessage.proto:8:18: Expected field name.*

Below is my .proto file.

```
package bluetoothmessage;

option java_package = "com.example.bluetoothexample";
option java_outer_classname = "ProtocolBuffers";

message BTMessage {
    required int32 cmd = 1;
    optional byte[] appData = 2;
}
```

A couple of other posts on stackoverflow mentioned that byte[] can be used as a filed and the below page also says the same thing.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [manual](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar): bytes May contain any arbitrary sequence of bytes.

The line:

```
optional byte[] appData = 2;
```

Must be changed to:

```
optional bytes appData = 2;
```